# IfxPy - Error to connect to Informix using python with IfxPy

Tags: python, database-connection, python-3.6, informix

I try to connect into a `Informix` Database using the module `IfxPy` , I follow all the instructions to install this module, but I could have a success connection.

I´m using Python 3.6 `IfxPy` module .

I already installed all preconditions package like wheel and twine.

I'm already connected with the module `jaydebeapi` but is too slow in terms of download data.

I use this code for get connect:

```
>>> import IfxPy
>>> ConStr = "SERVER=server;DATABASE=bd1;HOST=10.226.0.51;SERVICE=1445;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxx;"
>>> conn=IfxPy.connect(ConStr,"","")
```

Also this error appears with no helpful description:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
```

I expect to connect as I read, when try to connect... no comments appear after the successfully connection.

Someone knows how to resolve this issue or if I need to install other package or module.

Thanks.

Comment: The IfxPy module uses the Informix ODBC driver to connect to the server, which means you need to have CSDK installed before you can use the python module.  I would expect an error in the line of "cannot open shared library" if you don't have it, but it may vary from platform to platform.

Comment: Las librerias si existen. el CSDK esta instalado.
INFORMIXDIR=/home/informix/csdk410
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:/home/informix/csdk410/lib:/home/informix/csdk410/lib/esql:/home/informix/csdk410/lib/cli